# I put the ".chars" but I still have an array of characters

Tags: ruby

Like in the title. I put the ".chars" but I still have an array of characters,

look my terminal :

```
 1) caesar_cipher should echo Bfmy f xywnsl!
     Failure/Error: expect(caesar_cipher("What a string!",5)).to eq("Bfmy f xywnsl!")

       expected: "Bfmy f xywnsl!"
            got: ["B", "m", "f", "y", " ", "f", " ", "x", "y", "w", "n", "s", "l", "!"]

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/caesar_cipher_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't understand why I have an array of characters, while I put the `.chars` after the string

My code :

```
def caesar_cipher(string, shift)
    alphabet  = Array('a'..'z')
    non_caps  = Hash[alphabet.zip(alphabet.rotate(shift))]
    
    alphabet = Array('A'..'Z')
    caps     = Hash[alphabet.zip(alphabet.rotate(shift))]
    
    encrypter = non_caps.merge(caps)
    
    string.chars.map { |c| encrypter.fetch(c, c) }
end
```

Comment: have you thought of just using `.join` ? e.g. `string.chars.map { |c| encrypter.fetch(c, c) }.join`

Comment: You reference `chars` (which I assume is `String#chars`) 3 times in this post but it is not present once in the code? Please explain what your expectations are and what exactly is not working.

Comment: From the docs of `String#char`: _Returns an array of characters in str. This is a shorthand for str.each_char.to_a._ What do you `chars` expect to return?

Comment: Thanks a lot (a gain jad) ! .join is the solution. By reading the doc I thought that .chars was sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "map" operation will always return an array as it's output.

the options open to you would be to do string concatenation within an `each` clause, or to `join` the resulting elements from the array together into a string:

```
res = ""
string.each_char { |c| res << encrypter.fetch(c, c) }
res
```

or

```
string.chars.map { |c| encrypter.fetch(c, c) }.join
```